# sort options Url parameters '?' change to '&' so 404 error

Tags: magento-1.9, category, url-rewrite, sorting

in my category page, sort options url (Position, Name or Price) are

https://www.mywebsite.com/category/subcategory?dir=asc&is_ajax=1&order=position&type=195

https://www.mywebsite.com/category/subcategory?dir=asc&is_ajax=1&order=name&type=195

https://www.mywebsite.com/category/subcategory?dir=asc&is_ajax=1&order=price&type=195

but if i switch to another sort option like `position` to `price` for example :
`https://www.mywebsite.com/category/subcategory&dir=asc&is_ajax=1&order=price&type=195`

`?` change to `&` so i have 404 errors

The really strange things, on my Preprod or dev no issues, i was thinking of an `htaccess` issue

Thanks for putting me on right track.

Comment: Are you using any extension for listing?

Comment: The only extension in category page is Amasty's Improved Layered Navigation , but as i said Preprod and Dev no issues at  all (exact file match between branchs) so really  strange

Comment: @dimitrilongo have you got the issue, ca you help me with fix.